# Unable to connect to local Kibana console

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

A few months ago, Elasticsearch for a project was upgraded from version 7.x to 8.4.3. Prior to the upgrade, the following URL could be used to access the Kibana console and developer tools:

```
https://localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/console
```

However, this URL no longer works. Even if I try `http://localhost:5601`, I get a "Page is not working" error. The same error occurs when I try to access `http://localhost:9200` to check Elasticsearch's status. If I use curl, I receive either:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 after 2233 ms: Couldn't connect to the server
```

or

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The web application that uses Elasticsearch does not have any issues with Elasticsearch. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to access the developer console by using this URL instead:

`https://localhost:5601/elastic/kibana/app/dev_tools#/console`